# Java static instances and references

Tags: java, reference, garbage-collection, singleton, static-members

I have a singleton class. 
There is one more class that uses the singleton instance. Like below :

```
class A {
    SingletonDemo obj = SingletonDemo.getInstance() ;
. 
. 
. 
}
```

Now I know that the lifetime of SingletonDemo's instance inside SingletonDemo class is for the program's lifetime.

But what about the lifetime of obj in class A? 
Is it going to be garbage collected when control exits from class A or will it also live for the lifetime of entire program?

Comment: its not a new object in Class A, just a reference pointing to same singleton obj.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. The `SingletonDemo obj` field is a *reference* to the singleton. If you've implemented the singleton pattern correctly, there will be only *one* instance, which will, as you say, live on for the entire lifetime of the program.

Comment: Did you mean to declare `obj` as static?

Comment: Yes, the singleton stays the same from the point that `getInstance()` is first called until the Jvm dies. But the REFERENCES to the object from the user class drop in and out of scope.

Comment: @aioobe..  Look it's a proper singleton class and if you call getInstance(),  you can get the reference of it.

Comment: @user4582135, then there will be only one instance of the `SingletonDemo` class, right? You correctly point out that "the lifetime of SingletonDemo's instance inside SingletonDemo class is for the program's lifetime". Now if you know that A) that instance lives on forever, and B) there is only one instance, then you probably understand that "But what about the lifetime of obj in class A?" is a strange question to ask. Note that *references* doesn't get garbage collected. *Objects* get garbage collected.

Comment: Then what happens to references?  There is a section in memory map allocated for "obj" to point to the static instance right?

Answer (score 1):

- The Java specification states that the scope of the `obj in class A` is the entire body of `A`:

> The scope of a declaration of a member m declared in or inherited by a class type C (§8.1.6) is the entire body of C, including any nested type declarations.
>   See [JLS 6.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)

That means the reference `obj` will be garbage collected if control exits class `A`.

- Wether the singleton instance will live for the  life of the program or not depends on wether it is being used (it has a reference) or not. It can be unloaded if it is no longer be used/referenced. Here is what the specification says about it:

> An implementation of the Java programming language may unload classes. A
>   class or interface may be unloaded if and only if its defining class loader may be
>   reclaimed by the garbage collector as discussed in §12.6. See [Unloading Classes and Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.7)

If I understood correctly, a class is a singleton means that there is only one instance in the whole application but it doesn't mean that it will be available for the life of the application if it is not referenced at all.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I know that the lifetime of SingletonDemo's instance inside
>   SingletonDemo class is for the program's lifetime.

This portion of your question is the answer.

Because following line is not creating a new object, it's just creates a reference property of `class A` which referencing SingleTon object.

```
 SingletonDemo obj = SingletonDemo.getInstance() ;
```

So `obj` has no effect on SingleTon life time.

Comment: @DownVoter, Please give explanation what's wrong with this answer!

Answer (score -1):

You can imagine `A.obj` as a piece of memory - part of memory holding an instance of class `A` - that holds the *reference* to `SingletonDemo` instance.

`obj` per se cannot be garbage-collected; the `SingletonDemo` instance it points to may be garbage collected when there's no living strong reference to it anymore (i.e. never for a Singleton).

When the *instance* of class `A` is garbage collected, the memory storing the `obj` reference is discarded.

Answer (score -1):

`obj` is only a reference to the same static instance inside the `SingletonDemo` class. Only when both references are no longer available, the object will be garbage collected. And since the referenc inside the `SingletonDemo` class is static, it will stay in memory till the program exits.